# Search for an array of substrings within a string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, substring, nsrange

I want to check whether a string contains any of the substrings that I place in an array. Basically, I want to search the extensions of a file, and if the file is an "image", i want certain code to execute. The only way I can think of categorizing the file as an "Image" without downloading the file is through the substring in a string method. This is my code so far:

```
NSString *last5Chars = [folderName substringFromIndex: [folderName length] - 5];

         NSRange textRangepdf;
         textRangepdf =[last5Chars rangeOfString:@"pdf"];

         if(textRangepdf.location != NSNotFound)
          {
         [self.itemType addObject:@"PDF.png"];
          }
```

Is it possible to do this where I can check if last5Chars contains @"jpg" or @"gif" of @"png" etc...?? Thanks for helping!

Comment: To basically get the extension of the file. I didn't want to just get the last 3, since some files could have a longer extension. 5 just to be cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *fileName;
NSArray *imgExtArray; // put your file extensions in here
BOOL isImage = [imgExtArray containsObject:[fileName pathExtension]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[folderName hasSuffix:@".jpg"] || [folderName hasSuffix:@".gif"]
```

obviously you can put it into a loop, if you have a whole arrayful.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess about with ranges and suffixes, `NSString` has a method that treats an NSString as a path and returns an extension, it's called `pathExtension`.

Have a look in the [NSString Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Once you get the extension you can check it against whatever strings you want.